# Homemade prime number algorithm

Tags: prime-numbers, algorithms

I recently made a prime number algorithm that tries to find as many primes as possible. It starts with a few prime numbers: `[2, 3, 5, 7]`, starts its search at 9 and follows these steps.

1. Take the number (9) and square root it (3)
2. Go through the prime list and check if 9 is a multiple of any of the primes up to its square root (3)

   - 9 mod 2 = 1, so it is not a multiple
   - 9 mod 3 = 0, so it *is* a multiple and is composite
3. Add the number to the writing file queue and increment the searching number by 2.
4. Repeat until 50,000 primes are in the queue.
5. Write the queue into the file and repeat.

I was wondering if I could skip more numbers and predict when the next prime occurs. I then found that there is a certain pattern. After the number 2 squared (4), you can use binary and all of the primes will end in 1 (which is just a fancy way of saying that they are all odd). After 3 squared (9) multiply your base by 3 (So base-2 increases to base-6) and eliminate all multiples of 2 and 3 from the units value of base 6 (Which leaves us with 1 and 5). Now if we follow this search pattern we skip every 2 and 3 (alternating). After 5 (which is the next prime) squared (25), now you multiply 6 by 5, and use base 30 and eliminate all multiples of 2, 3, and 5... and so on.

Next this got me thinking. How can I use this algorithm to determine primes that are high numbers. Lets try this algorithm with numbers above, say, 19 squared (361). For this, our base is 2 * 3 * 5 * 7 * 11 * 13 * 17 * 19, which is 9 699 690. This number is massively higher than the numbers we want to calculate so now the algorithm doesn't work.

I was wondering if there is a more efficient version of this algorithm or if there is a completly new homemade algorithm to use other than this one. I know I can use the Miller-Rabin test, but I wanted to make a new algorithm myself. Any help on improving my algorithm is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What makes you think your approach is likely to improve on the Sieve of Eratosthenes? Before we spend time investigating your algorithm, you should give us some of your thoughts about the advantages of your ideas.

Comment: Your algorithm will for example check many numbers for divisibility by 1017. But only 1017, 2034, 3051 etc are divisible by 1017, so most of the work is in vain. Can you find all primes up to a billion, which is no problem at all with the Sieve of Eratosthenes?